# php xml parsing with simpleXML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have an XML file which I receive by post.

```
<response>
       <id>D234>/id>
       <Logs>
          <time>UTC</time>
          <Alarms>          
          </Alarms>
       </Logs>
</response>
```

Sometimes it may have few alarm logs

```
<response>
   <id>D234>/id>
   <Logs>
    <time>UTC</time>
    <Alarms>
        <Log>
            <LD>Reset </LD>
            <utc>1383704429</utc>
        </Log>
        <Log>
            <LD>Triggered </LD>
            <utc>1383601449</utc>
        </Log>
    </Alarms>
    </Logs>
</response>
```

I want to check if `<Alarms>` has children, and then form a query to insert them into db.
I tried xpath. I can find if children are there or not, and I can count. no problem.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(POST_DATA);
$alarms = $xml->xpath('Logs/Alarms');
echo count($alarms);
```

But how can traverse through each of the log? so that I can form a query to enter into DB. I am at a loss.

eg: how can I get `Log0->time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$alarms = $xml->xpath('Logs/Alarms/Log');
foreach ($alarms as $oneAlarm) {
    echo $oneAlarm->LD . "\n";
    echo $oneAlarm->utc . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to alter the looping logic. Please find this [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/rx4-yaq).

#### source code:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_string("<response><id>D234</id>
   <Logs>
    <time>UTC</time>
    <Alarms>
        <Log>
            <LD>Reset </LD>
            <utc>1383704429</utc>
        </Log>
        <Log>
            <LD>Triggered </LD>
            <utc>1383601449</utc>
        </Log>
    </Alarms>
    </Logs>
</response>");

$alarms = $xml->xpath('Logs/Alarms');


if (!empty($alarms)) {
    
   foreach ($alarms[0]->Log as $log) {
       
       echo $log->LD;
       echo $log->utc;
   
   }

}


?>
```

Comment: offcourse. Its what goes inside that is troubling me. I want to access each nodes inside the log node

Comment: thanks for the update. I am running xpath to get $alarms, and ->children() is not working on it. it throws an error. But Shazbot took me in the right direction. Appreciate it very much.

Comment: @aVC : No issues. Please check if it loops though the node values. If not, please refer to this, I have posted a working php fiddle with your xml data and code.